# Is not using & with a variable in scanf() a syntax error or a runtime error?

Tags: c, syntax, runtime

I was taught that a syntax error comes from a single mistake and doesn't execute the program. However, a runtime error still starts the program but crashes in the middle. If I accidentally didn't put `&` in front of a variable in a call to `scanf()`, would that considered to be a syntax error or a runtime error?

For example

```
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("input a integer number >>");
    scanf("%d\n", a);
    printf("the input number is %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

In the `scanf` statement, I don't have `&` in front of `a` so that would crash,
but it still executes the first `printf` statement, so it would show some printed text.

Is it going to be both a runtime error and a syntax error?

Comment: As you say, if it compiles, it's not a syntax error.

Comment: Technically neither. It's a constraint violation on the requirements of scanf, which results in UB (undefined behavior), which in turn *may* (and most often *does*) result in a runtime error, though that's not guaranteed by the language standard - it's just undefined. Compare to `printf(NULL);`.

Comment: It is not a syntax error, but it is a semantic error that some compilers will detect and report, and others will not (and those that do may have to be prodded into doing so by appropriate command line options).  The compilers are under no obligation to report the problem — that's a problem for the programmer, and/or a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: Note that it is not always necessary to use `&` with variables passed to `scanf()`.  For example, given `char data[32];`, it would be correct to write `scanf("%31s", data)` and incorrect to write `scanf("%31s", &data)`.

Comment: in C, when an array is referenced, the name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array,  so a call to scanf() with an array as a parameter does not need, not ever have, a leading `&`.   However, anything that is not a reference to an array (note: arr[x] is not a reference to an array but to a single item in the array) must have a leading `&`.

Answer (score 1):

## Depends on compilers intelligence

#### Some compilers are made intelligent to warn you for such obvious run-time errors

Comment: actually it depends on if the appropriate warning is enabled.  That is one of the major reasons to always, when compiling, enable all the warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) although I also like `-Wconversion` so I can either modify the code or include a `cast` to fix the 'implicit conversion' warnings

Answer (score 0):

Technically it would be both. It doesn't recognize it as an error until runtime. However as stated on [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) scanf expects pointers for the formatted variables therefore not preceding the variable 'a' with (&) is syntactically incorrect. Most would call this a runtime error and that is exactly what I would call it but its not completely wrong to call it a syntax error.  It is however more thought of as a runtime error since there is no error until it runs.

Comment: It isn't a syntax error; syntax errors prevent a program from compiling, but this code (give lax enough compilation options) will compile.  So, it isn't "both".